# Access i'th component of vector type

Tags: cuda, opencl

Is there a way of accessing the j'th component of a vector type such as `int4` ?
Here is how I currently do it, but is there an easier way ?

```
int4 temp = (int4)(10,20,30,40)
for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
   int component_j = shuffle(pix, (uint4)(j,(j+1)&3,(j+2)&3,(j+3)&3)).s0;
}
```

Comment: You could use a plain array, i.e. ’ int[4]’

Comment: thanks, if you add this as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 3):

There is [no `shuffle` op in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75633159/is-there-a-cuda-equivalent-to-the-opencl-shuffle-operation) so your proposed method won't work there.

As indicated in the comments you could do:

```
int temp[4] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
   int component_j = temp[j];
}
```

Another possibility if you want to preserve the vector type:

```
int4 temp = ...;
for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
   int component_j;
   memcpy(&int_component_j, ((int *)&temp)+j, sizeof(int));
}
```