# Is there a CUDA equivalent to the OpenCL shuffle operation?

Tags: cuda, opencl

http://man.opencl.org/shuffle.html

This shuffles the elements of a vector type, based on a mask. Is there an equivalent in CUDA ?

Comment: I don't think there is one in the generic sense. Cuda hardware is built on scalar registers therefore an efficient implementation is highly dependent on data type and whether the mask is a compile time constant. What's your use case? Where is the vector coming from? Where is the mask coming from? What's the data type?

Comment: thanks, @Homer512, I've decided to copy vector to array, where I won't need shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything equivalent in CUDA.

As already indicated, one possible approach would be to put the elements of a vector into an array, and do your work that way.